# Migrate website / application from IE6 to IE7 / IE8

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

At the moment I have to migrate a web-application (ASP.NET 2.0 with Masterpages) **from IE6 to IE7/IE8**. Where can I find **hints and guidelines** for this topic? The webapplication looks fine in IE6 but completely awful in IE7 and IE8. In IE8 I cannot see the compatibility button.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question which has specific answers. Like you rightly said you have to differentiate and list out all the "awful" looking items and then start fixing those for IE7 and IE8.

If there are funcationality issues related to javascript, try changing them to jQuery which will make sure it works in most of the browsers.

If the issues are related to design then you will have to ask specific questions to get clear answers.

Answer (score 1):

When moving a web application or site to operate with a different browser these situations can exist; that IE7 operates in a different jurisdiction or nation from IE6 and IE8; the laws and rules around IE7 may not allow some elements of webpage content like css or jscript or ecmascript or png or jpeg files or a different version and hosting server is required; the code or script behind NET is not fully runnable in some jurisdictions; some elements of the target computer operating system may be absent or different from the developer computer and environment; that NET is not lawful or legal in some nations.